# typesetting addition of fractions

Tags: fractions

I was wondering what the most efficient way is to typset this:

[image]

My first thought was doing this with tabular but seems quite messy to me.

Comment: xlop package does this

Comment: This is just multiplication of integers; there are no fractions, right? (Though one is visible just on the left edge of the image.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
first test:
\opmul[displayshiftintermediary=all]{15248}{3445}
 second test:
\opmul[displayintermediary=all]{15248}{3445}
 last test:
\opmul[displayintermediary=None]{15248}{3445}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `xlop`(a great package) there is also `basicarith`, which does some of the same things in a much more manual way.  (Disclaimer:  I'm the author of `basicarith` and therefore have the expected opinions about its usefulness.)  It was designed for basic arithmetic textbooks, so it allows for independent styling of individual rows or columns.  Your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{basicarith}
\begin{document}

\probline{12}{....912563}
\opline{$\times$}{....601894}
\nextpline{.....650252}
\nextpline{....213067\ }
\nextpline{...300504\ \ }
\opline{}{......63\ \ \ }
\soluline{.......4322}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following:

[image: basicarith typeesetting example]

Which, other than any transcription errors, seems pretty close to your handwritten example.

`basicarith` is manual, while `xlop` will do the work for you; in `basicarith`, as you can see, you must tell the package how wide your problem is in number of characters (the `\probline` macro), and manually say when you want an underline drawn (`\opline`, which takes the operation symbol as a first argument) or an overline (`\soluline`), and the answer is not calculated for you.  `xlop` avoids all this unpleasantness.  `basicarith` provides macros for Anglo-American style division, though (`xlop` only for European-style division, which is the primary reason I wrote `basicarith`).

`basicarith` also has lots of configuration options for customizing appearance; for example, you can step through a problem digit by digit, highlighting the appropriate lines or rows as you do so.  And you can solve as far as you want and then stop, allowing individual steps to be explained; you can resume the problem whenever you want.

I'd encourage you to examine these options and decide which is more appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: @dgoomaniii good work (basicarith)

Comment: Thanks!  I like it; but I am biased.

Comment: This is also a great solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: My compiler complains that "basicarith.sty" cannot be found. Does someone of you know how to fix this ?

Comment: The package is in TeXLive and on CTAN.  There should be instructions elsewhere on installing packages on your chosen system.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii This is a great package I really like that you can create any operation but Im kind of new using Tex and I really want to enumerate operations but I couldn't do it so I read the documentation but it didn't mention anything about it can you help me please Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, I'mafraid.

Comment: I would like to make a list of problems, i.e. enumerate them in order to my students solved them but I couldn't do it

Comment: Oh, I see. When I've done this, it's been in custom macros, b7t I think it should work in an `enumerate`.  Just wrap each problem in a `\problembox`.  If this doesn't work, email me, and we'll see if we can improve the package.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it, I just wrapped the problem on a minpage environment and it worked Thanks!!!!

Comment: @dgoodmaniii can you give your email please Im working with basicarith but Im having troubles with nextldline command I just only can add one line

Comment: It's on CTAN in the README.